# Split panel regression get one unique result in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, split, panel-data

I am working with a big data base but for sake of illustration I am using the `Grunfeld` data

My objective is to divide in chunks my data so my model can run, otherwise I run out of memory (90,000 gb needed). I am using `splm` for my data but since it works with `plm` I am using the latter for the example. Once I manage to run every chunk I will want to come with a general result.

What I have so far is this:

```
data("Grunfeld", package="plm")
Grunfeld <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld, index = c("firm","year"))
s1<-split(Grunfeld, sample(rep(1:4)))
fm <- value ~ capital
fix <- lapply(1:length(s), function(x) plm(fm, data=s1[[x]],model = "within"))
```

Now I have a list of coefficients and residuals `fix`

Is there a way I can create a function so my result emulate the solution of the complete data base instead of 4 chunks?

i.e.

```
Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-1299.602   -88.290   -10.197    84.142  1324.118 

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
capital 0.551055   0.098634  5.5869 7.971e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    23078000
Residual Sum of Squares: 19807000
R-Squared:      0.14174
Adj. R-Squared: 0.09633
F-statistic: 31.213 on 1 and 189 DF, p-value: 7.9714e-08
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting based on `nrow` of data frame. Below splits data into four chunks depending on data frame size.

```r
num <- ceiling(nrow(Grunfeld) / 4)
chunks <- ceiling(1:nrow(Grunfeld) / num)
fm <- value ~ capital

df_list <- split(Grunfeld, chunks)
fix <- lapply(df_list, function(df) plm(fm, data=df, model = "within"))
```

Alternative to `split`  + `lapply` is `by`:

```r
num <- ceiling(nrow(Grunfeld) / 4)
chunks <- ceiling(1:nrow(Grunfeld) / num)
fm <- value ~ capital

fix <- by(Grunfeld, chunks, function(df) plm(fm, data=df, model = "within"))
```

Comment: Thank you! but actually it doesn't work I got: ` Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'value' not found` for the lapply method and `Error in uniqval[as.character(effect), , drop = F] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions` for the by method. Besides df_list (for my big data) is 1.2 GB, while s1 is 10.3 MB
Also I keep getting a list of coefficients not an unique one

Comment: Increase `num`, the size of rows, to 400 or 4,000 or larger for 4 parts. How large is `Grunfeld`? Remember this subsets *entire* data frame, so `df_list` will be larger than `s1`. See edit splitting by four chunks.

Comment: Following `Grunfeld` example: I have 90 firms each for 744 years. When I chunk it `chunks <- ceiling(1:nrow(Grunfeld) / num)` I do it by firms but I need to chunk it in balance panels to run them in `plm`

Comment: Balanced panel may be a different question. You can use `split` and `by` to split by firms first and then run chunks on each split. To ensure non-missing years for panel requires additional work.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, let me come again with the question because this one is not clear, sorry